# How to configure Logback under Spring

Tags: java, spring, logback

Most of the examples for configuring Logback use logback.xml. However, my application uses Spring features of [profiles](http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/06/12/spring-3-1-environment-profiles/) and [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to inject environment-specific configuration into components that need it. What is the right way to configure Logback in a programmatic way just like my other Spring components?

Comment: via [Spring logback extension](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Spring) for example

Comment: @orid Thanks! Would you like to write this as an answer?

Comment: It's an old entry but for those who follow: Spring Boot has this built-in now, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html, chapter 26.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As orid pointed out, the official way to use Logback in Spring is with [the Logback Spring extension](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Spring).

The really cool thing is that the Logback Spring extension starts before Spring or the servlet and stores log messages until the Appenders are configured. (Simple appenders will be available immediately, while those that need Spring are proxied through `DelegatingLogbackAppender`).

In addition it allows you to:

- Use SLF4J's java.util.logging bridge.
- Specify the `logback.xml` location using a Spring [resource path](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) and [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) placeholders.
- Use the pre-set system property `webapp.root` (path to unpacked WAR directory) inside the `logback.xml` for setting log file paths, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In one of our projects, we had coded it like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator;
import ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException;
import ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter;

@Component
public class InitializationService implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Value("${logbackErrorMailPassword}")
    private String logbackErrorMailPassword;

    @Value("${supportEmail}")
    private String supportEmail;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String env;

    @Value("${log.dir}")
    private String logDir;

    @Value("${log.name}")
    private String logName;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        try {
            configureLogback();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void configureLogback() throws IOException {

        // assume SLF4J is bound to logback in the current environment
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        try {
            JoranConfigurator jc = new JoranConfigurator();
            jc.setContext(context);
            context.reset(); // override default configuration
            // inject the name of the current application as "application-name"
            // property of the LoggerContext
            context.putProperty("LOG_DIR", logDir);
            context.putProperty("LOG_NAME", logName);

            context.putProperty("ERROR_MAIL_PASSWORD", logbackErrorMailPassword);
            context.putProperty("SUPPORT_EMAIL_ID", supportEmail);
            context.putProperty("ENV", env);
            //jc .doConfigure(servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/my-logback.xml"));
            jc.doConfigure(new ClassPathResource("my-logback.xml").getInputStream());
        } catch (JoranException je) {
              // StatusPrinter will handle this
        }
        StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(context);

    }
}
```

`my-logback.xml` was residing at `src/main/resources`, looking like this:

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="10 minutes"> 
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_DIR}${LOG_NAME}.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
          <FileNamePattern>
           ${LOG_DIR}${LOG_NAME}-%d.%i.log.gz
          </FileNamePattern>
          <TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
          </TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
          <Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <!-- deny all events with a level below ERROR -->
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>

        <smtpHost>xxxxxx.bluehost.com</smtpHost>
        <smtpPort>465</smtpPort>
        <username>xxxxxxx+xxxxx.com</username>
        <password>${ERROR_MAIL_PASSWORD}</password>
        <SSL>true</SSL>

        <to>${SUPPORT_EMAIL_ID}</to>
        <!-- Multiple to elements are permitted -->

        <from>xxxxx@xxxxx.com</from>
        <subject>[${ENV}] ERROR in ${LOG_NAME}</subject>
        <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
              <bufferSize>1</bufferSize>
        </cyclicBufferTracker>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%date %-5level %logger{35} - %message%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="javax.net" level="info"/>
    <logger name="javax.management" level="info"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="info"/>
    <logger name="org.compass" level="info"/>
    <logger name="org.tuckey" level="info"/>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
        <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is simple and avoids another dependency. I wonder what the pros and cons are vs using the Logback Spring extension.

Comment: No idea. I'm unable to recall exactly: *Logback Spring extension* did not exist or why it wasn't considered the time our abovementioned project was coded.

Comment: I looked at the extension source code and wrote up the differences in my answer.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update. So, we should be using the extension henceforward, then.

Comment: For now, you can inject Spring properties and profiles into Logback configuration in more simple way: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_environment_properties